# Why fetch is called randomly?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to understand how exactly works adding new object to relationship, so I have this model (any person can be both teacher and student)
[image: model]

Let's take entity NVPerson and relationship coursesAsStudent.
I created new NVPerson object. 
Then fetched array of courses from database and added some of them to NVPerson, which this person should study as student

```
[self.person addCoursesAsStudent:[NSSet setWithArray:self.arrayToAdd]];
```

And this calls fetch randomly (it can be called, can be not called) and with random number of rows. for example
[image]

But result in a tableView is always right!

So, can it be some inner procedures, which are not relative to me right now?
And cache is off in fetchresultcontroller, if it can be useful info.
Why all this happened randomly, that's the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is bidirectional (as it should be) which means that when you add something to one end the inverse connection is made for you automatically at the other end. This is what you're seeing happen.

It isn't random, it just depends on what is currently faulted when you change the relationship. If all of the objects and relationship details are available then everything can be done directly, otherwise the details need to be fetched (faults fired) before that can happen.

Comment: Yes, thank you. When I add the same thing in second time after previous cancelling, fetching is not called. Looks like because of it is now in context after first fetch. 
Could you say from your experience, is it thing, that I must care about? for example in case of big data? should I prefetch all, what can be used in near future?

Comment: It's possible that pre-fetching could help, but I'd definitely profile using instruments and the core data tool before doing so (and after) to see what the main cost is slowing the app down.